# How to look after a bougainvillea

Tags: flowers, plant-care, planting

I just bought this bougainvillea but I need help on how to take care of it. 
Where should I plant it?
How much sun and water does it need?
And I dont know if it can survive the winter here because it goes down to -20°C.
A friend told me that if I leave it in the container for 2-3 years I can plant it in the ground and it would survive the winter. Does that work?

[image: bougainvillea 1][image: bougainvillea 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bougainvilleas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bougainvillea) start to get damage [below about 32 deg F](http://hort.ufl.edu/database/documents/pdf/shrub_fact_sheets/bousppa.pdf) or 0 degrees celsius.  At -4 degrees F or -20 Degrees celsius the plant is likely to be killed to the ground.

To winter over this plant bring it inside when temperatures get below 40 deg F or 4 degrees celsius and move it to a brightly lit location and keep it a bit on the dry side over the winter.  Move outside to a full sun location and water regularly.  Fertilize lightly, this plant is not a heavy feeder.

This is a big plant when mature so don't be afraid to cut it back in the fall. Trimming vigorous side shoots will be necessary to shape the plant. Be careful as it will grow sharp thorns.

This plant is considered low maintenance and is not subject to pests.